# SharePoint REST API: How to download List XML visible in browser to temp file C#

Tags: c#, xml, rest, sharepoint

I have been looking at exporting data from a company SharePoint site using C# written in VS Express 2013. First, a caveat - I'm new to web based APIs (Soap or REST) and SharePoint, so apologies if my question is prosaically easy to answer/ badly worded. Pretty much all of my previous work has been with files local to the machine or on a similarly local company network that can be accessed in the same way.

My aim - download a list from one site, do stuff to it on the client machine and then re-upload it to a different SharePoint site.

I have tried using the Soap API (Client object model) but I am encountering a variety of access and permissions issues. So I switched to the REST API, and have now managed to get the list data into XML within my browser. But I don't really want it in my browser - I want to access it programmatically, and write selected data from the list into a local file (using `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` to find the temporary folder), without browser windows popping up (except to allow the user to log in to establish an authorized context with the server). There has to be some trivially easy way of saving the XML data to my temporary file without needing a browser open, but I haven't been able to find it.

My REST query is like the following:

https://sk.someSharePointSite/sites/subsection/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/AList

Comment: Do you want to download and upload files from sharepoint?

Comment: Yes. I need to download from one SharePoint site, do stuff to the downloaded info on a local machine, and then re-upload it onto a different SharePoint site. It isn't essential to automate the upload process, but the download process I would like to automate.

Comment: You can check the following solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you should use Sharepoint client object model for downloading/uploading files to sharepoint.

If there is anything specific you can't do with CSOM then use REST API.

You can check the code details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524%28office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Aanachal, thanks for your response. However, the CSOM doesn't work for me (due to the sites security settings I believe). This was the first route I tried, but everything is "403 forbidden" or "HRESULT Access Denied". Basically, I have used the REST API to get the data I need - but it only appears in my browser when I enter the query as a URL. I want to grab all the data that appears when I do this via an automated process, and selectively write it to a local file.

Comment: Having followed the link you gave me (whilst it was one I had come across before) I can see that there is some useful information in there I had overlooked (hence the upvote)

Comment: Please check the credentials used in client context object. You shouldn't get access denied if you are using proper credentials.

Comment: I'm using SPO_AccessAWebService.ClaimsClientContext (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/12/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-web-services.aspx) to establish an authenticated session with SharePoint - is this incorrect? I have also tried using default log-in credentials (client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials) SPO_AccesAWebService require me to log on etc.

Comment: You log-in via a Microsoft Account (e.g. Outlook 365 etc). The ClaimsClientContext code opens up a browser window for the user to log-in to their account. After that, each site has slightly different security settings for standard internal users. I don't know the fine details of each one, unfortunately. I have contacted the site admin to get access, but I'm not sure they know much about the SharePoint APIs because they agreed to my request, changed a couple of things on my account, and now I can do stuff I couldn't do before, but no CSOM API access

Comment: Are you able to login to the sharepoint site? Are you sure the site is on claims based authentication?

Comment: I am able to log-in correctly via this route, yes, but I am not sure if the site uses claims based authentication... I got the ClaimsClientContext code from a Microsoft site for use with SharePoint, so I kind of assumed it did, but I guess we may have set up a different form of Authentication. I thought claims based authentication was standard with SharePoint?EDIT: I should have read this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc288475%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section2